# Convert Session to Guid

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, session, asp.net-membership

I am building a User Management section to a website CMS.

The user has a list of users and then clicks the edit button, the system then stored the UserId in a session and goes to the editUser.aspx page which will show the users details.

To get the users details I need to convert the UserId session to a Guid so i can get user details.

I keep getting error message:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

```
Dim selectedUserId As Guid = CType(Session("strUserId"), Guid)
Dim mu As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(selectedUserId)
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Guid.Parse()` instead. You are storing a string, so must convert from a string back to a Guid.

Comment: Tuiper: What is GuidParse? Would you be more specfic?

Comment: I dont know much about it, but this is what i found...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx

Comment: @Just Sung - Guid.Parse("123-12345-121213...") would return a Guid from a string, just as int.Parse("77") returns an int, just as DateTime.Parse("2011-06-28") returns a new datetime object. "123-12345-..." isnt a guid, its a string representation of a guid. We need to take that string here and go back to a Guid object.

Answer (score 0):

Is the strUserId a GUID value or a username?

If it is a GUID value, you cannot cast it but you can create a new GUID object using new GUID(strUserId).

If it is a username, your last line mu = Membership.GetUser(strUserId) should work without the cast.